# How can you re-assign (a.k.a set) class member that is unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
class A {};

class B{
    unique_ptr<A> upA;

public:
    B() : upA(make_unique<A>()) {}

    void set(A a){
        upA.reset(move(a));  //error
        //upA.reset(a);        //error
        //upA = move(a);     //error
    }
};
```

How can you re-assign (a.k.a set) class member that is unique_ptr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unique_ptr<A> upA;
```

so this is a unique (smart) *pointer* to an A located somewhere - fine so far.

```
B() : upA(make_unique<A>()) {}
```

OK, we initialize our pointer to point at a new, dynamically-allocated `A` - looks reasonable.

```
void set(A a){
    upA.reset(move(a));
```

but now you want to point your smart pointer - which is responsible for managing the lifetime of the object it points to - at a *local* instance of A? That doesn't make sense for two reasons:

1. your smart pointer manages a pointer, and you're passing it an (lvalue reference to) a local object. You could convert this to a pointer by writing `&a`, but this still has the problem that:
2. your local variable `a` will go out of scope when the function returns, leaving your smart pointer with a dangling, invalid address to attempt to manage.

When you call `B::set`, what is supposed to happen? You need to decide what it's intended to do from the caller's perspective. Either:

```
// transfer control of the caller's A to B
void B::set(std::unique_ptr<A> a) { upA = move(a); }
```

or

```
// take control of the caller's allocated but unmanaged A
void B::set(A *a) { upA.reset(a); }
// not recommended - keep everything managed by unique_ptr if at all possible
```

or

```
// copy the caller's A into B's existing A
void B::set(A const &a) { *upA = a; }
// called as
b.set(my_local_a);
```

or

```
// move the caller's temporary A into B's existing A
void B::set(A &&a) { *upA = move(a); }
// called with an explicit move
b.set(move(my_local_a));
// or with a prvalue
b.set(A{});
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you want to do. Do you want to invoke `operator=` on the object managed by `upA`? If so:

```
*upA = a;
```

Do you want to accept a new `unique_ptr` and take ownership of it? If so:

```
 void set(std::unique_ptr<A> a){
    upA = move(a);
}
```